# check retina image files missing

Tags: iphone

We have a project with a lot of images and their retina images.
Is there a simple way or tool to check if each image has its related retina image file?
I hope it will be a software tool or a simple script that can tell me which retina file is missed

Welcome any comment

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.splinter.com.au/quickly-check-for-any-missing-retina-graphics/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this python script. Note that it assumes @2x images will be in the same directory as the non-retina version. If you keep your retina and standard images in different folders, this won't work. It'll process files with `.png` and `.jpg` extensions as is, but it's easy to add more.

This uses the *nix `find` command to recursively get the path of every file in the current working directory. I'm a python newbie, so any comments/fixes/improvements are welcome!

You can run this manually, or you could use it in a pre-compile hook in xcode. It returns the path of files that don't have an @2x version.

```
from subprocess import check_output
from os import path
import string

# Get all the files in the current working dir, recursively
files_raw = check_output(["find","-type","f"]) 
paths = files_raw.split("\n")

# Remove the empty last element (find command ends with a newline) 
paths.pop()

for item in paths:
    # Ignore any @2x items
    if("@2x" in item):
        continue

    # Break up the path
    filename, extension = path.splitext(item)

    # Ignore files without these extensions
    if(extension not in [".png", ".jpg"]):
        continue

    # Make the rentina path and see if it's in the list of paths
    retina = filename+"@2x"+extension
    if(retina not in paths):
        print item
```

For example, for this folder:

```
.:
    file.txt
    john.png
    test@2x.png
    test.png    

./more:
    cool_image.jpg
    john@2x.png
    file.png

./other:
    [empty]
```

Running (in terminal):

```
cd /home/stecman/test-dir
python /home/stecman/missing-retina.py
```

Outputs

```
./john.png
./more/cool_image.jpg
./more/file.png
```

Comment: For other people checking this answer, I think the link in the 1st comment of the question is a better answer than this one (cf. http://www.splinter.com.au/quickly-check-for-any-missing-retina-graphics/). Why? 1/ It doesn't mind about the file system location of images 2/ It checks that images are actually part of an iOS target.